# Рекурсивный Фибоначчиев поиск

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, поиск, числа-фибоначчи

Очень нужна помощь, нужно реализовать рекурсивный Фибоначчиев поиск на C++.
Вот изначальный вариант:

```
int fibonacci_search(int arr[], int size, int target) {
    int fibm2 = 0;
    int fibm1 = 1;
    int fib = 1;

    int shift = 0;
    while (fibm1 + shift < size) {
        if (arr[fib + shift - 1] == target) {
            return fib + shift - 1;
        }
        if (arr[fib + shift - 1] < target) {
            fibm2 = fibm1;
            fibm1 = fib;
            fib = (fibm1 + fibm2 + shift < size) ? fibm1 + fibm2 : size - shift;
        } else if (arr[fib + shift - 1] > target) {
            shift += fibm1;
            fibm2 = 0;
            fibm1 = 1;
            fib = 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ещё б понять что вы понимаете под этими словами

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Этот код рабочий, просто он реализован с помощью цикла, а надо чтобы была использована рекурсия

Comment: ну используйте рекурсию. В чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 0):

Если упростить ваш код, то получится так

```
int fibonacci_search(int arr[], int size, int target) {
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(arr[i]==target)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Для того чтобы написать [рекурсию](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), нужно задать для нее базу с выражением return

```
return position;
```

и шаг рекурсии

```
return fibonacci_search_recoursion(arr,size,target,shift+1);
```

Все вместе выходит так

```
int fibonacci_search_recoursion(int arr[],int size,int target,int shift){
        if (arr[shift] == target) {
            return shift;
        }else if(arr[shift]<target && shift<size){
            return fibonacci_search_recoursion(arr,size,target,shift+1);
        }else return -1;
}
```

Comment: Вот только поиск из фиббоначчиевого стал линейным

Comment: Приведенный код в вопросе им не является

Comment: Является. [Вот последовательность шагов](https://onlinegdb.com/hzieEEl_Y) при поиске индекса 40000000 в массиве длиной 100000000